# 2015 Hyundai Sonata not accelerating

Tags: hyundai, sonata, acceleration

I recently purchased a 2015 Hyundai Sonata its only 2 months old and while driving on a freeway I was unable to accelerate. I was cruising at 65 mph and while trying to pass someone it just limped along very slowly going faster even though I had the pedal down to the floor and the RPMs were 4k to 6k. After getting to my destination I told the car off and tried restarting but it wouldn't start twice, after some time like 20 mins it started. Any thoughts on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you need to take it to the dealership and get it fixed. With Hyundai's warranty, this should not be an issue. As for the problem itself, it sounds like there may be a transmission problem (you say you were at 4-6k rpms, sounds like the engine is revving quite high). Check to ensure there is enough transmission fluid present.